requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Max retries exceeded

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /mockdata (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7a31938a60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

I use express to mock API for test in port=5000, and I use requests.get to check I can get a response, but in Airflow I got an error. Please help me.
My snippet code:
url = "http://localhost:5000/mockdata"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "deflate"
}
task_http_request = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id = 'http_request_to_express',
    method = 'GET',
    http_conn_id = 'http_express',
    endpoint = '/mockdata',
    dag = dag,
)


How are these 2 services run?
